# Oblique asymptotes condition for existence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, reference-request, rational-functions

In Stewart's Calculus book, the following is said:

> A rational function $f(x)/g(x)$ has an oblique asymptote (i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}|f(x)/g(x)-(mx+b)| = 0$) for some line $mx+b, \iff \deg f = \deg g + 1.$

The proof is not provided in the book. Can someone please *direct me to a resource that includes this proof?*

Comment: All you need to do is to write $f(x)/g(x)$ in "quotient-remainder form" and then consider 3 cases -- $\deg f < \deg g + 1$ (no finite limit exists) and $\deg f = \deg g + 1$ (finite limit exists) and $\deg f > \deg g + 1$ (no finite limit exists).

Comment: I see how that proves one direction, but not the "iff". How do I prove the other direction?

Separately, is there a resource (lecture notes, other textbook, etc.) that includes this proof, written out?

Comment: Unless there's something subtle I'm missing, if  $\deg f = \deg g + 1,$ then $f(x)/g(x) = (px + q) + h(x)/g(x)$ for some real numbers $p,q$ and polynomial $h(x),$ where $p \neq 0$ and $\deg h < \deg g$ (school algebra polynomial division), so by choosing $mx + b$ to be $px + q,$ we get $|f(x)/g(x) - (mx+b)| = |h(x)/g(x)| \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$; and if $\deg f \neq \deg g + 1,$ then by a dominate term argument, a finite limit does not exist.